# Get content of CMS block by identifier

Tags: magento2, plugin, cms-block

I need to create a module which lets the backend user add tooltips to the products custom options. So I created a field which the user fills with the unique identifier of a cms block which contains the text for the tooltip.

So my train of thought here was to create a plugin which appends the content of the given cms block to the html of my custom options.

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/OptionsBlockPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class OptionsBlockPlugin {

protected $resultPageFactory;


public function __construct
(
       \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
    ){
       $this->_layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    }

public function aroundGetOptionHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options $subject, callable $proceed, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $option)
{
     $returnValue = $proceed($option);
     $tooltip = $option->getData('tooltip'); //string of identifiert (for example: 'myBlock')

      if ($tooltip) {

          $block = $this->_layoutFactory->create()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Tooltip');
          $content = $block->getContent($tooltip);

          if($content){
              $returnValue = $returnValue.'<div class="option-tooltip">'.$content.'</div>';
         }

     }

        return $returnValue;
    }

 }
```

And my block class:

**Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Options/Tooltip.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options;

use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;


class Tooltip extends Template
{

    private $blockRepository;
    public function __construct(
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getContent($identifier)
    {
        try {
            $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($identifier);
            $content = $block->getContent();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $content = false;
        }

        return $content;

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I just can't get the content of my cms block by its identifier. Can somebody help me out a bit?

Answer (score 6):

I got it! The problem was the `getById()` method it DOES take a identifier as well as the id, my problem was that my test block had the identifier "123" and although it is a string either magento or php reads it as a numeric id in the method. So it is always was searching for the id `(int) 123` instead of the identifier `(string) '123'`.

Maybe seperate methods for getByIdentifier()/getById() would solve this.

Comment: Be careful to make sure identifiers are not shared between multiple store views, otherwise, you will not be able to specify which one to load. 

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10414

Comment: Right, I haven't thought about that, but thank your for the link, I'll update my module as soon as there is a method that takes the store id into account.

Answer (score 3):

Magento has the `Magento\Cms\Model\GetBlockByIdentifier` class for this purpose. Here is a usage example

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Product;

use
    Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView,
    Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface,
    Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifierInterface as BlockGetter,
    Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context as ProductContext,
    Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;

class Masterpiece extends AbstractView
{
    private
        $_oStoreManager,
        $_oBlockGetter;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $oStoreManager,
        BlockGetter $oBlockGetter,
        ProductContext $oProductContext,
        ArrayUtils $oArrayUtils,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_oStoreManager = $oStoreManager;
        $this->_oBlockGetter  = $oBlockGetter;

        parent::__construct($oProductContext, $oArrayUtils, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Look on the product to see if there is a value in the
     * 'custom_static_block' attribute. If it is, use that value to search
     * for a static block with that as an identifier. If found, return the
     * markup from the static block. Otherwise return the empty string.
     */
    public function toHtml()
    {
        $staticBlockId = trim($this->getProduct()->getData('custom_static_block'));

        if($staticBlockId == '') {
            return '';
        }

        try {
            $storeId     = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $staticBlock = $this->_oBlockGetter->execute($staticBlockId, $storeId);
            return $staticBlock->getContent();
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: best optimized solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use below Helper class to get CMS block per store views. (Tested and Working)

```
<?php
namespace {{COMPANY_NAME}}\{{MODULE_NAME}}\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $blockFactory;
    protected $blockResource;

    public function __construct(
        ...

        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block $blockResource,
        ...
    ) {
        ...

        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->blockResource = $blockResource;
        ...
    }

    public function getStaticBlock($identifier){
        try {
            $block = $this->blockFactory->create();
            $block->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $this->blockResource->load($block, $identifier);
            if (!$block->getId()) {
                throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('CMS Block with identifier "%1" does not exist.', $identifier));
            }
            return $block;
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            //$this->logger->warning($e->getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getCmsBlockContent($identifier){

        $staticBlock = $this->getStaticBlock($identifier);

        if($staticBlock && $staticBlock->isActive()){
            return $staticBlock->getContent();
        }

        return __('Static block content not found');
    }
}
```

To use this class in `.phtml`:

```
<?php
$helper = $this->helper('{{COMPANY_NAME}}\{{MODULE_NAME}}\Helper\Data');
echo $helper->getCmsBlockContent("CMS_BLOCK_IDENTIFIER");
?>
```

> NOTE: You can use this class for Blocks too

Comment: FYI, there is the `Magento\Cms\Model\GetBlockByIdentifier` class which implements your `getStaticBlock` method. Assume there was some copy & paste here? Also, why would you `try` and `throw` inside the same piece of code...

Answer (score 0):

same as @Anil Suthar answer but uses GetBlockByIdentifierInterface and returns \Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface

```
<?php

    namespace {{COMPANY_NAME}}\{{MODULE_NAME}}\Helper;

    use Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifierInterface;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

    class YourMethod {

        $protected $getBlockByIdentifier;

        $protected $storeManager;

        public function __construct(
            GetBlockByIdentifierInterface $getBlockByIdentifier
            ,StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
            ){
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->getBlockByIdentifier = $getBlockByIdentifier;
        }
    
        public function yourMethod(){
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $block = $this->getBlockByIdentifier->execute('Block Identifier',$storeId);
        }
    }
```